# MPAndroidChart set highlight color

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Just wondering if anyone has figured out how to set the highlight color for a bar chart in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)? Currently it's like a dark black (somewhat transparent) overlay. I would like to make it a white (somewhat transparent) overlay, and maybe even a gradient. Kind of like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`BarDataSet`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/BarDataSet.java) extends [`BarLineScatterCandleBubbleDataSet`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/BarLineScatterCandleBubbleDataSet.java) which has a `setHighLightColor` method:

```
/**
 * Sets the color that is used for drawing the highlight indicators. Dont
 * forget to resolve the color using getResources().getColor(...) or
 * Color.rgb(...).
 * 
 * @param color
 */
public void setHighLightColor(int color) {
    mHighLightColor = color;
}
```

The `BarDataSet` also has a `setHighLightAlpha` method:

```
/**
 * Set the alpha value (transparency) that is used for drawing the highlight
 * indicator bar. min = 0 (fully transparent), max = 255 (fully opaque)
 * 
 * @param alpha
 */
public void setHighLightAlpha(int alpha) {
    mHighLightAlpha = alpha;
}
```

Neither of these methods would support a gradient but you can change the appearance of the highlight.

If you are looking to implement the gradient highlighting you can probably extend the [`BarChartRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/BarChartRenderer.java) and override the `drawHighlighted(Canvas c, Highlight[] indices)` and apply it to your chart via the `setRenderer` method (I haven't tried this personally).